# Java Swing component does not repaint automatically

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am debugging a Java Swing application in which a component (in my case a JButton inside a JPanel inside a JPanel) does not get repainted automatically when it should. For example, when the window is first shown, one can see the JButton there, but when another window overlaps my application's window for a while, the JButton can no longer be seen.

Since I have no idea where to begin, I would like to know what are the most common causes of repainting problems in Swing components.

Comment: If the `Swing` application is not started on the [Event-Dispatcher-Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), such situations might can arise :-) Are you starting your application from the `main` thread ? If you are, time for you to read that tutorial page :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw yes, of course.

Comment: __"yes, of course"__ Is it `yes, of course` my application is using main thread for GUI related updates. Or is it the other way around ?!!! :-) Isn't the code responsible for creating and displaying your GUI, wrapped inside `invokeLater()` ?

Comment: of course it is yes of course my application was started in the event dispatch thread

Comment: Then its time to edit the question with the code. There must be something you doing wrong in the code, since, such thingies are not bound to happen.

Comment: Another good way to get weird effects is trying to modify components or layout during the painting.

Comment: There are too many ways for this to go wrong; please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good place to start at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html

Comment: "Check whether repaint is invoked on your component whenever its appearance needs to be updated." This is the kind of thing that is completely useless to me, because I don't know when its appearance needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you minimize both the windows and bring them back on?
you might try calling your jpanel.revalidate() at some point in your code. But I don't know where to call that unless I see your code.